# codeigniter get method name from parent method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want get the method name. For example, A url call the `method1`, and call the private `method2`, the `method2` want to know who call this method. How could I do it.

I can use `__FUNCTION__` or `$this->router->method` on the `method1`, and put it as `method2` parameter. But I want to know could I on the `method2` to get this method is called from `method1`? Thanks a million.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ControllerName extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function method1()
  {
      $this->_method2()
  }

  private function _method2()
  {
    // How to get call method name method1,
    // Don't use parameter 
    // $who_call_me = 'method1';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the debug_backtrace() function. i guess its the only way to know if you cant use parameters.

```
$callers=debug_backtrace();
echo $callers[1]['function'];
```

if you just want to know the previous method which calls, use array_shift. it will show result like-

```
$caller=array_shift($callers);
echo "Called by {$caller['function']}";
```

Comment: The `$callers` array is like stack? For example `method1->method2->method3`, array should $caller[1]['function'] = method2, $caller[2]['function'] = method3

Comment: yes. it makes an array. or if you just want to know the previous method calling, you can use array_shift. i will edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your url but u can do something like this..

```
 function getNameOfOriginatingClass{
     $this->load->library('user_agent');
     $previous_url = $this->agent->referrer();
     $url_segments = explode('/',$previous_url);
     echo '<pre>';print_r($url_segments);    
 }
```

after printing this result u can see your link broken into parts in an array.. Normally the $url_segments[3] or $url_segments[4] will contain your previous function name and previous one will contain previous class name depending upon your url.

Comment: but what if someone rewrites his url? i guess its not a good idea to depend on urls for your codes.